# Is there a way to hook up my SNES to a modern A/V receiver?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, snes

I have an SNES console hooked directly into the back of my TV in the coaxial RF antenna port.

However, I would like to be able to switch to-and-from the console with my AV receiver.  I currently only have Component (YP<sub>B</sub>P<sub>R</sub>) and HDMI ports available on the back of my receiver.

**Is it possible to hook up an SNES to a home theater system?**

Comment: Are you sure your TV has no S-video input?

Comment: @Joe You just found a reason for gaming.SE to require MathJax/LaTeX support :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is to get an SNES/N64/GC S-video cable, and use a third-party [s-video to component adapter](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=off&q=s-video+to+component+adapter&aq=f&aqi=g2g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

The system came with a stereo A/V cable (red/white/yellow), and Nintendo also sold a first-party S-Video cable. SNES, N64, and GC used the same multi-out port, so if you have trouble finding an SNES S-video cable, try searching for N64 and GC S-video too. (GC also had a separate port for component video output.)

**Note**: the multi-out port on [the smaller, redesigned SNES model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Nintendo_Entertainment_System_%28Redesigned_Model_SNS-101%29) will not work with the S-video cable. If you only have the redesigned system you'll need to use a composite-to-component adapter instead.